# Optimizing CAD application to be more efficient

Tags: c#, performance, cad

I'm developing CAD like application in C# (Forms, no external framework). I have implemented pan, zoom, select; but it’s very slow, because on every mouse move it redraw all lines.

How to build app to be faster and more efficient? How to redraw just one line?

code for drawing (on standard Panel):

```
void pan_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Entitie o in sketch.Entities)
    {
        if (o is Line)
        {
            Line l = (Line)o;
            Point p1 = pointScreen(l.P1.X.CurrentValue, l.P1.Y.CurrentValue);
            Point p2 = pointScreen(l.P2.X.CurrentValue, l.P2.Y.CurrentValue);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, p1, p2);
        }
    }
}
```

for drawing new line:

```
void pan_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (tmpEntitie != null)
    {
        Line l = (Line)tmpEntitie;
        l.P2 = e.Location;
        pan.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use C#? Given the libraries involved for even the most basic application most things you do with drawing will be latent. Also, if you haven't already I suggest looking in to something like [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/)

Comment: Can you show your code? Also, .NET is pretty good with graphics, so even if you redraw on every mouse move, there shouldn't be a problem if you only redraw the changing area each time.

Comment: .NET is plenty fast for most graphics applications if you approach it right.  Hint: Calling SetPixel over and over is not the way you want to go :-)

Comment: Having your question tagged C# isn't really enough in the way of explaining what you're doing. We at least need to know if you're using Forms, WPF, or some other framework in order to be able to make meaningful suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use a space partitioning technique which divide the space in regions or quadrants and redraw the objects only if they are in the region showing in the current  viewport.

Here are some links to start:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Libraries:

http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/jtshome.htm (Java Topology Suite)

http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/ (JTS in C#)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do it to learn stuff: you already have answer for the first step - you've identified what takes long time and when ("every mouse move it redraw all lines"). Next step is "do I need to do whatever I'm doing" before "can I do it faster". You likely don't need to redraw everything on mouse move - try and measure, see if it is good enough for you. Redrawing everything 1000 times/second will take long time but will not be visibly different from doing it 60times/second (or even less).

If you find yourself on "can I do it faster" - define your goals and measure what you have first. Search for "double buffering" if you want to stick with basic, consider proper 3d framework DirectX/XNA or OpenGL, see if WPF works for you.

Comment: This is my first drawing app, so I would like to learn basic theory behind CAD and vector apps. Double buffering looks like a good suggestion.